# Compiler is creating extra class files with $ in them

Tags: java, compilation, javac, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I'm using Eclipse and I've written a Java application using SWT. When Eclipse compiles my program, it renames my main file into 4 different files like this:

- MainFile.class
- MainFile$1.class
- MainFile$2.class
- MainFile$3.class

When I go to run this program from command line, I get

> Could not find the main class: MainFile.class. Program will exit.

I really don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Can you show is the line from the command line that you ran to get this error?  Like, `lowasser@gowers$ java MainFile` or whatever.

Answer (score 5):

The `$` classes are for anonymous inner classes and perfectly normal.

Could we see the command line you ran?  You probably need to write `java MainFile` instead of `java MainFile.class`.

Comment: I've tried both. I'm glad that's normal although now I really don't know why it won't run from terminal.

Comment: Could you actually show us the command line in your question?  That would help us figure out what's going on.

Comment: @user, If your MainFile class is in a package, then you need to make sure you are saying `java my.package.MainFile` with the classpaths properly set.

Comment: In fact even the "anonymous" is misleading a little bit. For anonymous inner classes a number will be appended after the $, like in the sample. For non-anonymous inner classes the name will be used.